# PDOException could not find driver Laravel With php 7 Xampp

Tags: command-line, 16.04

i'dont understand about migrate operation on ubuntu, and i have this error, please help me to solve this problem

[image]

Comment: install this `sudo apt install php7.0-mysql` and restart apache

Comment: Have you already checked this link? [Laravel 5.4 on PHP 7.0: PDO Exception - Could not find driver (MySQL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42909397/laravel-5-4-on-php-7-0-pdo-exception-could-not-find-driver-mysqlc)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html)? If so, just run `php artisan --host=localhost:8000`, or with your prefered port.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! In its current form your answer is not as good as it could be. Could you review [How to Write a Good Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7659), and [Style guide for questions and answers](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/89/style-guide-for-questions-and-answers). - [From Review](https://askubuntu.com/review/late-answers/792116)